# Looking to either Explode or unnest into an array in Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the past I've used either the explode function(sql) or unnest in (bigquery) to expand one row into several. For instance I've transformed the current data row: [image]
into the following:
[image]

Does anyone know if snowflake sql has a function which allows me to do this? I can't seem to find one

Comment: I don't know snowfalke but does it help ...https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/generator.html

Comment: How would you do it in BigQuery? I think the solution would be the same in Snowflake.  I think the best way is to join onto a CTE which uses a generator to add days to the `signup_date` for each `id` but how many days do you want to extend forward? I don't think there is enough information in your example to provide a complete solution.

Comment: Hey @SimonD, I don't have the query handy but you could flatten the data structure by using the unnest function. See here: https://ken-williams.com/guide/reporting-analysis/how-to-flatten-a-bigquery-table-with-unnest/. I don't think Snowflake has a similar unnest function

Comment: There is an equivalent function in Snowflake called flatten but your example data (in the first table) cannot be flattened because it already is flat. That's why I asked how you'd do it in BigQuery, because it doesn't appear to make sense to me and I wanted you to be more explicit. link to flatten: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generator()`:

```
select t.id, t.subscription, t.signup_date,
       dateadd(month, row_number() over (order by null) - 1, t.signup_date) as tenure
from t cross join
     table (generator(row_count => 12));
```

I'm a little baffled on why you think you would do this with `explode()` or `unnest()` in another database.  The key idea is generating the series, I think, not turning it into rows.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I don't know why, but when I add the cross join the result comes up blank. The rest of the query works. Do you know why?

Comment: Does the `table(generator( . . . ))` expression work by itself?